# Drop down selected value should be posted as string to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an application where I need to pass selected value of a dropdown along with model on form post method back to controller. The dropdown field isn't a part of my model so it's value doesn't pass to the controller on it's own on form post. I want to achieve this without using ajax or javascript. Kindly help?

Here is my controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]     
public ActionResult Create(List<ClassSubject> ci, string U_Dropdown)
{
          // db logic 
}
```

View code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "coursesubject", new {//have to pass dropdown selected value as string here  }, FormMethod.Post)) 
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownList("name", new SelectList(ViewBag.SelectedDepartment, "Value", "Text"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    //// my model fields
}
```

Comment: Change the parameter in the method to `string name` to match the name of the dropdown.

Comment: Ok, and what shall I pass in BeginForm for the new{}?

Comment: Nothing. `DropDownList()` creates `<select>` and its the value of the select you want.

Comment: You can get `DropDownList` selected text value by `jQuery` then assign it to your model hidden input.

Comment: @SeM, Why in the world would you even consider doing that?

Comment: Stephen, I remember you from the other thread where you had proposed to use viewmodel instead of whatever I was trying to do, and yet again you have saved my life with this. it worked. Thanks so much! (:

Comment: @Poonam, And you should be using a view model in this case too - containing 3 properties, one for the collection of `ClassSubject`, one for the value of the dropdown and one for the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. And you code suggests `ViewBag.SelectedDepartment` is already `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` so creating another identical one from it by using `new SelectList()` in the view is pointless :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, did exactly like you said. Worked. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the value to text in Selectedlist and 'U_Dropdown' for  DropDownList name

```
@Html.DropDownList("U_Dropdown", new SelectList(ViewBag.SelectedDepartment, "Text", "Text"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

or simply u can put

```
@Html.DropDownList("U_Dropdown", new SelectList(ViewBag.SelectedDepartment), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Thanks :) I used something like the second one.